# Searching Salesforce Content

Tags: apex, content, libraries

How do we search the Salesforce content body(docx/pdf) in Apex. I wasn't even able to search by tagcsv, **filtering by tagcsv is not supported**. Can someone please guide me on this. Thanks!

```
content = Database.query('select id,TagCsv from ContentVersion Where Title Like \'%'+searchstring+'%\'');

return content;
```

I get a error when I try to filter the query by tagcsv, and I don't find a way to search the body.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to share the code you tried and specific error message?

Comment: are the PDF's OCR'd ?

Comment: @cropredy what do you mean by OCR'd?

Comment: If PDFs are scanned images, then unless Optical Character Read (OCR) by some software before saving in `ContentVersion`, their contents won;t be searchable

Comment: @cropredy not the images, I don't find any way searching docx or text files either.

Comment: are you using SOSL?  You'll need to post some code

Comment: @cropredy added the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search `tagcsv` or `body` in ContentVersion, you have to use SOSL.

I created a library, contributed a Word docx file with the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

and a tag of `sfse`

These SOSLs executed in the DC Query Editor returned the ContentVersion document:

```
   FIND {sfse}  in ALL Fields returning ContentVersion   
   FIND {Duis}  in ALL Fields returning ContentVersion
```

You can't use SOQL to query `ContentVersion.body` as it is saved as a Blob

[Documentation reference for SOSL and ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_returning.htm?search_text=contentversion)

> External objects, articles, documents, feed comments, feed items,
>   files, products, and solutions must be specified explicitly in a
>   RETURNING clause to be returned in search results. For example:
>
> FIND {MyProspect} RETURNING MySampleExternalObject,
>   KnowledgeArticleVersion, Document, FeedComment, FeedItem,
>   ContentVersion, Product2, Solution

Comment: Thank you! one last thing how do I refence sosl in apex:repeat?, isn't it var.fieldname? I don't see that working.

Comment: @cartman. Look in detail at how apex and sosl work. You specify which fields you want to retrieve. You end up with lists of lists of sobjects. One of the inner lists can be used as `value={!mergefield}` for the `apex:repeat`